# Graphics does not display during Linux dual boot install on Mac OS X

Tags: macosx, usb

I am currently running a 2015 Macbook Pro with Yosemite 10.10.2.
I downloaded Linux Mint 17.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 both of which are 64 bit versions. I manually created a live USB for each OS using the instructions found on the Ubuntu [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick). I also installed rFEInd bootloader. When I boot the Mac the live USB does not show up in rEIFind's menu but by booting while holding the alt-key I am able to go into a live session of both Ubuntu and Mint, but when I try and install the distos by clicking on the "install linux" icon, the window shows up but no buttons or any other graphics is displayed. I tried by directly installing Ubuntu instead of "trying Ubuntu" but that just ended up with a pure grey install screen.
Any suggestions on how I may fix this? Thanks